# Javascript: Iterating through properties of object and assigning them to a new object

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
var self = this;
var test = function (name, properties) {
    self[name] = {
        prop1: "test1",
        prop2: "test2"
    };

    // some code here assigning properties object to self[name] object
};

test("myObj", { "prop3": "test3", "prop4": "test4" });
```

What I need to accomplish is assign the content of the `properties` object to `myObj` so that in the end:

```
self["myObj"] = {
                prop1: "test1",
                prop2: "test2",
                prop3: "test3",
                prop4: "test3"

            };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery has a method for extending objects called [jQuery.extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/)

You can have a look at how jQuery has implemented this [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L265).

You would use it like so:

```
$.extend(self, { "prop3": "test3", "prop4": "test4" });
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just add a foreach if the objects are simple (might want to add hasOwnProperty() check if not)

```
foreach(var propertyKey in properties) {
    self[name][propertyKey] = properties[propertyKey];        
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Replace the commented line in your function (`//some code here assigning ...`) with this

```
for(var i in properties) self[name][i] = properties[i]
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/BeNae/1/)

Or better

```
for(var i in properties) {
    if(properties.hasOwnProperty(i)) self[name][i] = properties[i];
}
```

[**DEMO>**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/BeNae/2/)